# How to iterate struct variables in c# without using reflection?

Tags: c#, struct, iteration

In my project I have to change the endian-ness of the data types like int, float, short etc. I thought that the best way to do is to access the elements of the struct then change the endian-ness of them (if they are bigger than 1 byte). The struct is very long, it is necessary to do this in an automatical manner.

ex struct:

```
struct
{
int a;
short b;
char c;
int d;
int e;
float f;
char g;
int h
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to use reflection, I suggest you write a parser that can iterate through the source, and create the proper source code automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can't iterate class/struct members dynamically without reflection. You should either try a different approach, or consider using reflection.

---

Edit:

You could try aligning your struct data to 4-byte boundaries with:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
struct ExampleStruct{ ... }
```

Then you would access your struct data through an `unsafe` raw pointer and ignore preceding 0-value bytes for each 4-byte chunk.

Comment: The issue being that int = 4 bytes, short = 2 bytes, char = 1 byte, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make your .cs file copied to the output directory (Debug). Now you can do anything with your text! Parse it !

Cheers!